# logging all BigQuery queries

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to have all BigQuery requests logged to a file in Cloud Storage (or even better into a BigQuery table)?  It seems like the --apilog option available in bq is intended mainly for debugging purposes, but what I'd like to do is keep track of all queries, just like logging all access requests on a particular file in CloudStorage.

To be more specific, I don't just want to log my own queries, but (a) queries by all users within the same project, and optimally also (b) queries by *anyone* touching a table in a dataset that I own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its late, but GCP in its latest releases introduced this new feature of Audit logs.

Refer this - [Audit Logs BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)

Answer (score 6):

In the CLI, you can run `bq ls -j -a` to retrieve jobs for **all** users in a project. You can redirect all output to a storage file.

Then you can run for each job id a `bq show -j <job_id>` and in order to have more details you will choose to use the json response:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson -j job_joQEqPwOiOoBlOhDBEgKxQAlKJQ
```

this returns the following format which have your query, your user and bytesprocessed etc...

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "dryRun": false, 
    "query": {
      "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED", 
      "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "", 
        "projectId": "", 
        "tableId": ""
      }, 
      "query": "", 
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    }
  }, 
  "etag": "", 
  "id": "", 
  "jobReference": {
    "jobId": "", 
    "projectId": ""
  }, 
  "kind": "bigquery#job", 
  "selfLink": "", 
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1435006022346", 
    "endTime": "1435006144730", 
    "query": {
      "cacheHit": false, 
      "totalBytesProcessed": "105922683030"
    }, 
    "startTime": "1435006023171", 
    "totalBytesProcessed": "105922683030"
  }, 
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  }, 
  "user_email": ""
}
```

Using the API you need to pass allUsers property to list jobs from all users https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list#allUsers

Comment: What would be awesome would be some sample code for regularly running that query and appending new results to a BQ table. It wouldn't be terribly difficult to write, but I'm sure someone out there has already done it.

Comment: You may want to add the number of lines `bq ls -j -a -n 1000` to show more than the last 50 queries.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better way to do this now with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

Here's a simple way to get all queries from a project in the last 90 days:

```
 SELECT
   job_id,
   start_time,
   user_email,
   total_bytes_processed,
   query
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
 AND job_type = "QUERY"
 AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
```

Full documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery has the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*` view to retrieve real-time metadata about BigQuery jobs. This view contains currently running jobs, as well as the last 180 days of history of completed jobs.

For more info see [Getting jobs metadata using INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs)