# How can I see jobs from all users in the Web UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

Our backend service runs BigQuery jobs using it's own account. And as an administrator I would like to see those jobs in the Web UI. Is there some permissions I can set or query parameters I can use to do this?

Comment: This is not directly programming-related. I'm voting to close.

Comment: actually it is, it has to be computed a query

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

You need to first setup [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs).

Once you have it in a table (maybe next day) you can write a query to list all jobs

a simple query is:

```
SELECT 
protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail,
protopayload_auditlog.methodName,
protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.query,
protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobInsertResponse.resource.jobName.jobId,
protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobInsertResponse.resource.jobStatistics.createTime
FROM [wr_auditlogs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20171208] 
where protopayload_auditlog.serviceName='bigquery.googleapis.com'
```

which will list these things

- email who executed (user,service account)
- method name eg (jobservice.insert)
- query string if this was a query job (there are extract and cancel jobs as well)
- the jobID
- the created time

You can setup this or more advanced query as a view, and you can query this view periodically. You can retrieve also via API, see that discussed here [logging all BigQuery queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150542/logging-all-bigquery-queries)

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to view jobs and queries from other users in the web UI. You need [bigquery.jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) permission for this.

To list queries, in the UI, go to "Query History", and be sure to check "show queries for all users". You are then able to filter the queries on the user you are looking for.

To list jobs,  in the UI, go to "Job History". You are then able to filter the queries on the user you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the permission `bigquery.jobs.listAll`

You can find this permission in some of the predefined roles.

[image]